# Backbone: populating of tables works but corresponding loop data not changing

Tags: backbone.js

I am using backbone to populate the table and then be able to edit the contents using modals implemented in bootstrap.
The table populates very well but on clicking edit on the modal, all field contain data of the first entry only

Here is the code,

```
<tbody> 
                         <%  users.each(function(user){ %>
                            <tr>                                
                                <td>
                                    <%= user.get("first_name") %>
                                </td>
                                <td><%= user.get("last_name") %></td>                           
                                <td><%=  user.get("gender") %></td>
                                <td >
                                    24 years                                
                                </td>
                                <td >
                                    <%=  user.get("email") %>                               
                                </td>
                                <td class="hidden-480">
                                    <%=  user.get("phone_number")%>                             
                                </td>
                                <td class="hidden-480">
                                    <%=  user.get("role") %>                                
                                </td>

                                <td>
                                    <div class="visible-md visible-lg hidden-sm hidden-xs action-buttons">
                                        <a href="#modal-form" role="button" class="blue" data-toggle="modal"> 
                                            <i class="icon-pencil bigger-130" id="user_edit" ></i>
                                        </a>
                                        <a class="red" href="#">
                                            <i class="icon-trash bigger-130" id="user_delete" ></i>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>                       
                            <div id="modal-form" class="modal" tabindex="-1">
                                <div class="modal-dialog">
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                            <h4 class="blue bigger">Edit User</h4>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-body overflow-visible">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-xs-12">         
                                                    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label no-padding-right" for="form-field-1"> First Name </label>

                                                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                                                <input type="text" id="user_first_name" value=<%= user.get("first_name")%> class="col-xs-10 col-sm-10" />
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div><br>
                                                        <div class="space-4"></div>
                                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label no-padding-right" for="form-field-1"> Last Name </label>

                                                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                                                <input type="text" id="user_last_name" value=<%= user.get("last_name")%> class="col-xs-10 col-sm-10" />
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div> <br>
                                                        <div class="space-4"></div>
                                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label no-padding-right" for="form-field-1"> Date of Birth </label>

                                                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                                                <input type="text" id="user_date_of_birth" value=<%= user.get("date_of_birth")%> class="col-xs-10 col-sm-10" />
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div><br>
                                                        <div class="space-4"></div>
                                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label no-padding-right" for="form-field-1"> Gender </label>
                                                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                                                <select id="user_gender" class="col-xs-10 col-sm-10 ">
                                                                    <option value="Male">Male</option>
                                                                    <option value="Female">Female</option>                                      
                                                                </select>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div><br>
                                                        <div class="space-4"></div>
                                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label no-padding-right" for="form-field-1"> Phone Number </label>

                                                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                                                <input type="text" id="user_phone_number" value=<%= user.get("phone_number")%> class="col-xs-10 col-sm-10" />
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div><br>
                                                        <div class="space-4"></div>
                                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label no-padding-right" for="form-field-1"> E-mail Address </label>

                                                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                                                <input type="text" id="user_email" value=<%= user.get("email")%> class="col-xs-10 col-sm-10" />
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div><br>
                                                        <div class="space-4"></div>

                                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label no-padding-right" for="form-field-2"> 
                                                                Password 
                                                            </label>
                                                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                                                <input id="user_password" class="col-xs-10 col-sm-10" type="password">
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div><br>
                                                        <div class="space-4"></div>
                                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label no-padding-right" for="form-field-2"> 
                                                                Confirm Password 
                                                            </label>

                                                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                                                <input id="password_confirmation" class="col-xs-10 col-sm-10" type="password">                      
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div> <br>

                                                        <div class="clearfix form-actions">
                                                            <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-9">
                                                                <button class="btn btn-info" type="button" id="user_submit">
                                                                    <i class="icon-ok bigger-110"></i>
                                                                    Submit
                                                                </button>

                                                                &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
                                                                <button class="btn" type="reset">
                                                                    <i class="icon-undo bigger-110"></i>
                                                                    Reset
                                                                </button>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>

                                                        <div class="hr hr-24"></div>                                
                                                    </form>                                             
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>      
                        <% }); %>  
                    </tbody>
```

Comment: can you show some code from your view? How do you listen and handle the events? My guess is you are binding the event on the composite view level but you have a button for each row...

Answer (score 1):

In your loop you are assigning an ID to the modal and this is giving them all the same IDs. Maybe the bootstrap JS is only showing the first one that it finds which is why you see the same one every time. Maybe you if you appended the ID of the user or something unique to the ID of the modal this would work.

For Example:

```
<div id="modal-form" class="modal" tabindex="-1">
```

and

```
<a href="#modal-form" role="button" class="blue" data-toggle="modal">
```

could be changed to:

```
<div id="modal-form-<%= user.get('id') %>" class="modal" tabindex="-1">
```

and

```
 <a href="#modal-form-<%= user.get('id') %>" role="button" class="blue" data-toggle="modal">
```